# Redirecting hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

The Table \hyperlink{mark}{1} are in the appendix of this article.

\newpage

\section*{Supplementary archive}

The supplementary material can be accessed at this \hyperlink{mark}{link}.
\end{document}
```

I want to click in the table number "1" and to be redirected to the word "link" (at the final of the document) that accesses the article's supplementary file. How can I do this?
The provided code does not do what I want.

Comment: the second should be \hypertarget{mark}{link}